# Deleting a directory fails after using sudo to copy

Tags: sudo, files, directory, copy

Using sudo command I copied entire directory to another directory.
I need to delete the directory now but it's asking permissions. 
How can I delete?

Answer (score 0):

Just use sudo again:

```
sudo rm -r [path to folder]
```

you can use additional options:

- `-f` (force)
- `-I` (prompt)
- `-v` (verbose, explain)

if you need.